# Validate if another field is empty laravel validation

Tags: laravel, validation, required

I want to validate field if present and will fail if another field not present
How to do it ? I have create custom validation to get record based id on storage

I have field `product_id` and `amount` and the `amount` field validate between max and min based on `product_id`, if i present the `amount` = `100000` and not fill the `product_id` field the validating for `amount` field is passed and display error because i am not fill the `product_id` i want check before the custom validation execute will check if `product_id` empty or not..

I have read all validation method on laravel docs still didnt find the solution.
How to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found a solution...

on Form Request class i just add `sometimes` rule on validate instance so when the `product_id` field not present on `amount` field will not validate and when present it will validate using validation rules like this:

```
class StoreRequest extend FormRequest
{
    protected function getValidatorInstance()
    {
        $validator = parent::getValidatorInstance();

        $validator->sometimes('amount', 'required|numeric|max_amount:product_id', function ($input) {
           return Arr::has($input, 'product_id');
        });

        return $validator;
    }
}
```